# Threshold Value for Random Forest Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

Is there any way to set a threshold value that can be set for voting results for Random Forest Classifier in sklearn package in order to prevent any misclassification for incoming test data.

Comment: Your question is too broad. In any case, I recommend you to check [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112388/how-to-change-threshold-for-classification-in-r-randomforests)

Answer (score 1):

Yes and the most important parameter is the tree depth. It's a pre-pruning technique that allows to prevent overfitting. Specifically for sklearn is:

```
estimator.tree_.max_depth
```

I suggest you to perform GridSearch on max_depth:

```
params = {'max_depth':[1,50]}
gs = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeClassifier(), params)
gs.fit(X,y)
```

where X is you training set containing instances
and y are the labels.

There are packages that also support post-pruning like this one https://svaante.github.io/decision-tree-id3/